# Why doesn't redirecting output from nginx work?

Tags: output, pipe

I want to list all modules of [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) server by line, so I type the following:

```
nginx -V | tr -- - '\n'
```

But it doesn't put modules in lines. If I do it like this:

```
2>&1 nginx -V | tr -- - '\n'
```

it works. But why?

Comment: because `nginx -V` writes its output to the standard error stream (file descriptor `2`) rather than the standard output stream (file descriptor `1`)?

Comment: aha, thanks, and basically this `2>&1` says redirect output from error stream (2) to standart output (1) ?

Comment: yes that's correct - I have expanded my comment as an answer

Comment: I know this is old, and applies to Linux / Ubuntu, but this _ALSO_ applies to Windows.  They are still doing this, even at version 1.22.1.  Life saver right here - been searching for this for hours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're observing indicates that `nginx -V` writes its output to the standard error stream (aka `stderr` - on file descriptor `2`) rather than the standard output stream (aka `stdout` - file descriptor `1`). Only `stdout` gets passed through the pipe `|` so your `tr` command doesn't receive it.

The `2>&1` syntax tells the shell to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so that it then gets piped to `tr`. FYI the placement you have used is syntactically legal but unconventional - most often that kind of redirection would be written as

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | tr -- - '\n'
```

BTW the pipe `|` is really redirecting the *output* of the first command rather than the *input* of the second, which is coming from the standard input stream (`stdin` - file descriptor `0`) as usual.